# Didn't Receive Email—What Happened

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm learning Salesforce Marketing Cloud and experienced some unexpected behavior today.

I sent a message to a number of data extensions. The number of recipients was upwards of 70,000. Before I sent the official email I sent a test specifically to my address. Everything looked good so I used Guided Send to send to the data extensions.

This was 4 hours ago and I have not received the message yet but my coworker who sits across from me has. This coworker and I likely would have been in the same data extension.

I verified that my name and email address are in the data extension. Does it just take this long to distribute to a huge list? Did it not send to me since I received a test send? Or is something likely wrong?

I checked all folders in my email and do not see it.

Thank you

Comment: I know you said you checked all folders - but once when I was absolutely certain I wasn't receiving a system email, I remembered I had setup a rule in Outlook that marked all emails from support@salesforce.com as read and filed them in a trash folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be something that would be better asked to general support or your account rep...

But to answer your question as best I can, depending on volume, frequency and many other factors, the email can take [days to be delivered](http://ask-leo.com/how_long_should_email_take_to_be_delivered.html). This is very unlikely to  be the case, but is potential and considered acceptable behavior by mail transport.

I would also check your spam folder as if you have not had the IP/domain (server and clientside) white listed, with repeated sends(tests), it may have wound up there.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what happened.

A different user was the one who sent the email. I initiated the import of the data into the data extensions and was going to go assist this person in the send. By the time I arrived at their desk they had already sent it.

Given that some of these data extensions were rather large I assume this person sent the email before import had finished (which would explains the partial send on many of the lists and no sends on others).

Viewing the past sends section shows a number that reflects the total number of recipients because now, 4 hours later, the import had completed.

Time to go send again I guess....

Comment: you should make sure to export the already sent emails(from tracking) and import into a list to use as exclusion list on your new send. This way people do not get 2 of the same message.